# How do I leave free space for grub when copying a whole system to a new media?

Tags: linux, partitioning, grub

I've tried to copy a whole system to a new media. Like the existing layout, I'd like to use an everything-in-one-partition approach.
This is what I've tried:

- create a partition table and one single partition using gdisk (also creates a protective MBR)
- create a file system (ext4) on that partition
- mount it
- rsync the old / to the target partition (excluding mounts like /sys, /proc, ...)
- remove the old media
- boot the new system using the "Super Grub2 Disk"
- grub-install (on the whole disk)
- reboot

At first, it looked like it worked, but the grub-install seems to have corrupted the file system. This could be fixed by booting a rescue system and do a fsck, but after that, grub was broken. Fixing grub again corrupted the filesystem again.
So I can move back and forth between a corrupted filesystem and a broken grub.

After doing some research, I understand that grub stores its early stages in free space before the first partition, but stage 2 should be a normal file.
When creating the partition, I've used the default values suggested by gdisk. And looking at the partition table again, there is some free space before the partition. I don't really get why my approach failed.

How do Linux installers handle this and how can I replicate it manually?

**Edit:**
It looks like I've generalized my question a bit too much...
My actual use case is to migrate a virtual machine from vmware to KVM/Quemu/libvirt/virt-manager. Unfortunately, I could not directly convert the disk image, because it is a chunked image, and the vmware-diskmanager failed to convert it to a single-file image, which would have been necessary to convert it to a qcow2 image. So the rsync approach is already Plan B. I also omitted that the target VM was running a live CD image in order to have a working rsync "receiver".
The old as well as the new VM are BIOS-based (not EFI). But there is no separate bios_grub partition. Instead, the single big partition is marked as bios_grub. Here is the partition list shown in `gdisk`:

```
Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048        25163775   12.0 GiB    8300
```

And yes, I did `grub-install` on the whole disk.

I have no problem with doing the procedure again and create a separate bios_grub partition, but I still would like to learn how Linux installers do it without.
I've experimented a bit and created a new virtual machine and installed Debian on it. I've chosen the option "All on one partition" and the result looked like the partition list above. I've also checked that the installer created a GPT partition table although the VM is running in BIOS mode.

Answer (score 0):

> After doing some research, I understand that grub stores its early stages in free space before the first partition, but stage 2 should be a normal file.

That's only true for BIOS-mode boot and only when using MBR partitioning. The GRUB kernel aka "core image" gets installed before the 1st partition, built with enough modules to find your /boot partition with the grub.cfg + module files.

(There are no "stages" in GRUB 2; that terminology was more common in the BIOS-only GRUB 0.x. So if you see mentions of "stage 1.5" or "stage 2" then you're reading an outdated text – the current architecture only divides things into the core image and modules, much like the Linux kernel works.)

For BIOS/GPT the free space is no longer used, in part because *the GPT* is there. Instead, grub-install requires a dedicated mini-partition (unformatted) to hold the core image. It's technically possible to avoid it, but that would only make the process more messy; the purpose of that partition is to avoid the problem you're having.

UEFI boot process is completely different; instead of a 440-byte boot sector, the firmware itself loads a file from the "EFI System Partition" as the bootloader, which can be large enough to contain the whole GRUB core image. (This is usually the `grubx64.efi` or `bootx64.efi` file.) In this boot mode, the EFI System Partition is no longer a GRUB-specific thing but is still mandatory to have, and it must be a FAT32 partition.

> At first, it looked like it worked, but the grub-install seems to have corrupted the file system. This could be fixed by booting a rescue system and do a fsck, but after that, grub was broken. Fixing grub again corrupted the filesystem again.

It feels like you've installed the bootloader to the wrong place; perhaps into sda1 instead of sda: *or* you had two overlapping filesystems mounted.

In normal operation, grub-install never writes anything to your "root filesystem" partition in a way that would bypass the filesystem; at most it copies files to /boot/grub using standard file operations.

> How do Linux installers handle this and how can I replicate it manually?

They don't try to put everything in a single partition; they create the EFI System Partition when it's needed.

First decide on the boot method you want to use. (Most PCs have UEFI style firmware that increasingly starts to lose support for BIOS boot mode.) Then create partitions that are needed for that boot mode; if an EFI partition is needed, set it up to be mounted at /efi or similar.

When installing GRUB for BIOS, specify the whole disk as device. When installing it for UEFI, don't specify any device but do specify `--efi-directory=` (and if your rescue system is not booted in EFI mode itself, add the `--removable` option as well).

You don't need to boot using Super Grub2 Disk for this; you can chroot and grub-install from the system you use to rsync everything.

Comment: Whow ... that was insightful and also helpful. But it looks like I've generalized my question a bit too much in the first version. Please see everything below "Edit"